# Creation of matrix in python 3

Tags: python, matrix, list-comprehension

I want to create such matrix:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1],[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9]]
```

My attempt was:

```
[[x if x<=5 else x-5 for x in range(x,5+x)] for x in range(1,6)]
```

but I gives me a little bit other result:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 1], [3, 4, 5, 1, 2], [4, 5, 1, 2, 3], [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

What should I change in my code?

P.S I want to dou it wih list comprehensions, list operations and lamda's. Without numpy and other scientific packages.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `9` in the last list is a typo, you appear to be looking for

```
[[abs(i) for i in range(j, j+6)] for j in range(0, -6, -1)]
```

which in my machine gives the result

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[abs(j) for j in range(0-i,6-i)] for i in range(6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use an `if` expression. The "trick" is to generate the numbers that count down to zero as negatives and then convert them to positive using the `abs` function; number that are already positive will be unaffected.

```
size = 6
r = range(size)
m = [[abs(j-i) for j in r] for i in r]

for row in m:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Of course, the matrix can be generated in one line:

```
m = [[abs(j-i) for j in range(6)] for i in range(6)]
```

but the earlier code is slightly better because it re-uses a single range object instead of creating new range objects on each inner loop.